# How to get entries with partial keys (in any order) in map c++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, data-structures, stl

Assume below are the entries in a c++ map with key as some structure.
0, 1 in the below map need not necessarily be only integers/string. It can also be any user-defined data type.

```
---------------------
Key          | Value
---------------------
(0, 0, 0, 0) | a
(0, 0, 0, 1) | b
(0, 1, 0, 1) | c
(0, 1, 1, 0) | d
....
```

Below are different queries to look-up in map:

```
1) (0, 0, 0, 1) -> b
2) (0, *, *, *) -> [a, b, c, d]
3) (0, 1, *, *) -> [c, d]
4) (*, 1, 1, 0) -> [d]
5) (*, *, 0, 1) -> [b, c]
6) (*, 1, 1, *) -> [d]
7) (*, 0, *, 1) -> [b]
```

The idea is to have '*' anywhere in the key, and do the look-up efficiently without iterating over all the entries.
`'*'` indicates wild card (it can be anything).
Can anyone suggest on how to solve this problem ?

Comment: This is not what `std::map` is for. `std::map` cannot be used for something like this. No C++ library container can. You'll need to design and implement your own map-like container that provides this kind of a partial lookup functionality.

Comment: Maybe a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie); With every step select the branch according to the selector value or all branches on `*`. With only 0/1 values a binary search tree would do the trick as well (even array based), but you'd need to implement on your own as `std::map` does not allow to iterate over the nodes in the way you'd need to.

Comment: This seems to be another form of the "auto-complete" problem, thus a trie as suggested by @Aconcagua looks like the better option.

Comment: If you must use a `std::map` for this for some reason, and if your keys are all bit flags like in the example, then you can pretty efficiently generate a sequence of all of the keys matching a given wildcard pattern by looping over `key = (key - mask) & mask;`. See TAOCP 4A §7.1.3 p150, "Working with fragmented fields".

Comment: Something like a [`boost::multi_index_container`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html), where you index each permutation of `is_key_present`?